# How do I export test plan onto excel from HP ALM when there are multiple folders

Tags: alm

How do I export testplan from ALM  to excel when there are multiple folders and I want only specific folders out of them.

I have tried using all list and description name but not working as expected.
The query above is fetching all the data of test plan even though where condition has AL_description =<'folder name'>.

Comment: are you trying it from ALM user interface or from API?

Comment: I have tried from ALM user interface by using query.